# How to plot a collection of linear models from a list in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

I'm doing an exercise from *R for Data Science* that asked me to fit a linear model to a few runs of a simulated data set. I did this manually, but then wanted to expand on the idea. I attempted to expand on the idea based on a solution from another website. That solution is the following:

[image]

The problem with this solution for me is that I'm not familiar/comfortable with using `methods` yet. So I made an attempt to recreate this solution based off of the knowledge I know. What follows is my solution with comments and the point at where I'm stuck.

1. First I generated the data to use in this exercise:

```
simt = function(i) {
   tibble(
    x = rep(1:10, each = 3),
    y = x * 1.5 + 6 + rt(length(x), df = 2),
    .id = i
  )
}

sims = map_df(1:12, simt)
```

2. Since I want to have multiple linear models I separated my data into a list of data frames, using the `.id` as a reference. I partitioned the list using a `for` loop:

```
partition_sims = list()   #initialize a list of data frames

for(i in 1:10){                                     #Created a for loop to partition the large data frame  
  partition_sims[[i]] = filter(sims, .id == i)        #into a smaller data frames and put into
  }                                                   #my list of data frames. Note the use of [[ instead 
                                                      #of [. Needed to do this to select the 
                                                       #individual data frames for list
```

3. Next step was to create a list of linear models, by calculating the intercept and slope for each respective data fame. I put this collection of linear models into a list as well. I did this by writing another for loop:

```
lm_list = list()    #initialize list of linear models

for(i in 1:10){
  lm_list[[i]] = lm(y ~ x, data = partition_sims[[i]])
  }
```

So here is where my problem begins. I've been trying to attempt to plot my collection of linear models against the original data set `sims`. What I envisioned was plotting each linear model individually against the original data set that corresponds to its `.id` number and displaying it all together in a facet.

As a play example of what I was attempting to do, I tried plotting one linear model against the separated data frames:

```
ggplot(data = sims, mapping = aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_abline(intercept = coef(lm_list[[1]])[1], slope = coef(lm_list[[1]])[2]) + facet_wrap(~.id)
```

That worked, so I wanted to expand on that. I viewed my challenge as trying to somehow replicate the `geom_abline` command over not one element in my `lm_list`, but all of them. So I want the loop to work on something of the form:

One thing I thought could work was perhaps to take advantage of R's recycling vectors feature, so I wrote  a `for` loop to extract the necessary values and put them into vectors:

```
vec_of_slope = vector()
vec_of_inter = vector()

for(i in 1:10){
    vec_of_inter[i] = coef(lm_list[[i]])[1]
    vec_of_slope[i] = coef(lm_list[[i]])[2]
}
```

Then put these vectors into my `ggplot` command:

I got closer, but the problem with this one is that all ten linear models are plotted on each data frame.

The last idea I had was perhaps making a list of plots and then faceting them based on their index number in the list. Once again I tried to fill the list out with a for loop:

```
collection_of_plots = list()

for(i in 1:10){
    collection_of_plots[i] = ggplot(data = sims, mapping = aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_abline(intercept = coef(lm_list[[i]])[1], slope = coef(lm_list[[i]])[2])
}
```

Well this attempt shot me a `In collection_of_plots[i] <- ggplot(data = sims, mapping = aes(x,  : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` error. So needless to say this didn't work either.

So I appeal to the knowledgeable folks here, what can I do to rescue this solution?

A few disclaimers:

1. I know there are probably a lot cleaner solutions than the one I'm presenting. I wasn't looking for the sleakest at this moment. I'm trying to understand the foundations first.
2. I am using the Tidyverse package
3. How do you get the text to be colourful when writing out questions?

EDIT:  I may have gotten a step closer. I decided to make a tibble of the intercepts and slopes:

```
collection_of_plots = tibble(
  interc = vector()
  slope = vector()
)

for(i in 1:10){
  collection_of_plots[i,1] =  coef(lm_list[[i]])[1] 
  collection_of_plots[i,2] =  coef(lm_list[[i]])[2]
}
```

Still not complete, but perhaps closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some more `purrr` magic (for-loops will also do) as well as `broom` and a bit of `tidyr` this could be achieved like so:

1. Split the data with `split()`
2. Make the models by `purrr::map`ping over the splitted data
3. Make a list of tidy model results using `broom::tidy`.
4. Bind the list of results in one df using `dplyr::bind_rows`.
5. For easy plotting use `tidyr::pivot_wider` to bring the df into the right shape
6. Use the original data in `geom_point`s, use the df with model results in `geom_abline`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

simt = function(i) {
  tibble(
    x = rep(1:10, each = 3),
    y = x * 1.5 + 6 + rt(length(x), df = 2),
    .id = i
  )
}
sims = map_df(1:12, simt)

# Split with split
partition_sims <- split(sims, sims$.id)

# Make models by "map"ping over the the data
lm_list <- map(partition_sims, ~ lm(y ~ x, data = .x))
# Make a tidy df of model results by using broom. 
# Bind the single models in one df using bind_rows.
# For easy plotting use pivot_wider to bring the df into the right shape
lm_tidy <- map(lm_list, broom::tidy) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = ".id") %>% 
  select(.id, term, estimate) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "term", values_from = "estimate")

# Plot. Use original data for points, model results for abline
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = sims, mapping = aes(x, y, color = factor(.id))) + 
  geom_abline(data = lm_tidy, aes(intercept = `(Intercept)` , slope = x)) + 
  facet_wrap(~.id) +
  guides(color = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The solution is very nice and makes clear sense to me, thank you for that. But I'm having difficulty installing the ```broom``` package. I'm wondering if it's because it is still very new that there are bugs in it, but after installing it, I try to load it to my work station using ```library("broom")```, but get an error saying it doesn't exist.